# Sharepoint site access issue

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to check with the experts here. What the root caused of below issue?

We have problem access to SharePoint side from window explorer, for instance the sharepoint side is \teamspace.abb.com\xxx . If we access this from window explorer, it returned Window cannot access \teamspace.abb.com\xxx

But if access this from internet explorer, it works and we are able access it.

Anyone know what could cause this issue happened ?

Comment: Do you know if you have webdav enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after installed desktop experience feature !!